# Submit content of SPS 2013 custom form to Email

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, form

I`ve a custom form using SPD 2013 and remove save and close button.
Added Submit button and would like to associate a workflow to submit the form content to a specific email id.

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Please suggest how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirements below,

1. *Content filled in the form on submission to be email.* - Use SharePoint designer workflow to send email once the form is submitted. Refer the link here to create a SPD WF, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4
2. *Save button on the form to be replaced with Submit* - Use the below JavaScript to change the text 'Save' to 'Submit'. Edit the newform.aspx page, add a script editor webpart and add the below script in it.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready( function () {
        $("[name$='diidIOSaveItem']").attr("value", "Submit"); //change value of Save button to Submit

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can u elaborate Something and provide clarity on what steps to follow.

Comment: What does your custome form do actually?

Comment: custom form ask for basic details (first name, last name, company address, etc....) need the information to be shared via email id with the authorized person.

Comment: Why do you need a custom form here? You may achieve it in a simple sharepoint list itself. I think you should create a simple list with all the fields you need. On saving an item use SharePoint Designer workflow to send email.

Comment: Will test and update soon

Comment: I can add the custom text on the newform.aspx, need to perform the following and need expert view:

a) Content filled in the form on submission to be email.
b) Save button on the form to be replaced with Submit

Comment: I think you may use the new answer above.

Comment: Thanks Nagarajan for your assistance. I`ve gone through the article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4

Sorry cant find how can I get the content from the form on email?

Comment: an update - I was able to create a workflow that will fetch data from the form and email it .

Here are the steps -

Click on the email action in your workflow (it means it should be selected).
Next go to the advanced properties in the ribbon, if you click that "Send an Email Properties" dialog box will be opened.
Select Body Field and fill out all the field values by perform Add lookup as shown in the screen below.

Img link: http://imgur.com/AVbnbUN

Comment: JavaScript didn't worked to change the button value to Submit, can you please update. Also how can I get a customized thankyou page post submit and not the allitems.aspx page.